# carousel leaving pixels after moving

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a controllable carousel with the following code.

---

**HTML**

```
      <div id = "blanket">
            <div id = "carousel">
                <img id = "cr" src = "img/cr.png"/>
                <img id = "te" src = "img/te.png"/>
                <img id = "mi" src = "img/mi.png"/>
                <img id = "ga" src = "img/ga.png"/>
                <img id = "ro" src = "img/ro.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
#carousel{
    height: 100%;
    width: 500%;
}
#carousel img{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    border:1px solid white;
}
#blanket{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    right: 5%;
    top:7%;
    height: 75%;
    width:64%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

---

**jS(jQuery & GSAP included)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

})
$(document).click(function() {
var i = event.target.id;
if(i=="yl"){
    gets(0);
}
else if(i=="gt"){
    gets(1);
}
else if(i=="br"){
    gets(2);
}
else if(i=="rb"){
    gets(3);
}
else if(i=="gb"){
    gets(4);
}
});
function gets(i) {
var off = -1 * (i * $('#carousel img').width());
TweenLite.to($('#carousel img'), 0.7 ,{left:off+"px",ease:Power2.easeOut});
}
```

The problem is that the carousel does not move in sync with the images ie. some pixels of the previous image creep into the next pane. What to do?

Comment: a jsfiddle/ with all the pieces may help us to help you.

Comment: Which exact browser version and all JavaScript libraries which you use?

Comment: i am developing on chrome 37.0.2062.124 m with GSAP(tweenlite, CSSplugin, easepack) and jQuery 2.1.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/m7vjs3gy/)  - jSfiddle Note the pixels on the left at the 3rd pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by tinkering with the CSS. Initially all the images were not stacked side by side even after giving the rule `margin:0`. So I gave a negative margin and also increased the size of the containing `div` ie. `carousel` to account for the negative margins.

So the images were stacked and did not overflow to the adjacent panes.

The jSfiddle has been edited.

http://jsfiddle.net/m7vjs3gy/2/

EDIT : Just became aware of the fact that line breaks and other whitespace in HTML makes `inline` elements have invisible margins. To effectively remove the invisible margins, clean up the whitespace, as has been done in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m7vjs3gy/3/